# What's the diff between Empty and No Value for Docker Volumes From?

Tags: docker

I'm listing containers' VolumesFrom and saw this odd discrepancy:

```
$ docker ps -aqf status=exited |
  xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.VolumesFrom }}' |
  sort -u
[]
[4ba0ed650507f81d1598b43ecf6643ef34726330a6302c88b2ad98f5b960ae3e]
[e74e8f53425c]
<no value>
```

Among other things I see an empty list `[]` and `<no value>` output. What difference does it make to a container if it has no value for `.HostConfig.VolumesFrom` or just no members in its list?